# Cannot query snowflake external S3 stage with path

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have few files in the S3 bucket and I have created a stage for it. When I query the stage, I get the filenames.

[image]

The SnowFlake's [Query stage documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage.html) says, I can query by adding path along with the stage name `@[namespace.]external_stage_name[/path]`. So, I ran the query again with the path but now it doesn't list any files. What could have gone wrong?

[image]

Comment: What is the URL used in the external stage?

Comment: The URL is set in storage integration and the stage is created using the reference of the storage integration.

Comment: My point was more to: does the URL contains the **/path** already maybe?

Comment: @Sergiu thanks a lot asking me to check the URL. The stage had the path already `s3://<bucket_name>/aggregrated-data`. I ran `ls '@raw.cis_snowpipe.aggregated_data_stage/demand_pool';` and it did work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storage integration used in the stage had a URL that contained already the **/path**, therefore using **/path** in the LS command made the **/path** to be present twice and giving an empty result set.